# How to float images without stacking them?

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive design that mostly works.  Images are in their own DIV, and that div is floated left or right. Captions for the images are in the div, so they stay with the image.  By default image div width is set to 30%

If I put sufficient text between successive divs I get a pleasing display, with the text wrapping around the image.

If the images are too close, however they stack, and I end up with 2 images floating next to each other, and a tiny column of text.

The use of "clear" eliminates the text too.

Is there a way to float a div so that:

- Text flows around it.
- A second image does not stack adjacent to it even if there is nominally room for it.

In essence I want to float an image, but ensure that it is flush to the left margin, and not be on top of something else.

At this point my process is to try each page at multiple effective widths, and add more text/move the div as needed.  This is fairly time consuming.  I expect with a bit of time I will find out that I need X words between DIVS,

In some cases, I will stack multiple images within a single DIV.  This works well for related images.

Example of a page with the issue about 3/4 of the way down the page.:

http://sherwoods-forests.com/Trees/Leaf_Trees/Poplars/Columnar_Poplars.html

CSS file for the site:

http://sherwoods-forests.com/2col.css

Comment: Can you please add code examples?

Answer (score 0):

Put the floated image DIVs *into*  the text container, not as a sibling to the text container. That way the text should float around it and won't be affected by a `clear` in one of the image DIVs.

If that doesn't work, you'll have to post your code - this general answer is all I can give you without the actual code...